# Changing background-image on carousel navigation click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a Bootstrap Carousel and I am trying to change the background (an image) to coordinate to a specific slide slide. I have 4 slides and 4 background-images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My name</title>


    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/styles.css">

    <!--- Font Awesome ------->


    <!-- bootstrap script -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body id="ed-body" class="bg-img0">
    <section id="education">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="ed-carousel">
          <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-interval="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="slide-box">
                  <h3 class="slide-title">college 1</h3>
                    <img class="college4-seal" src="public/images/college1-seal.png" alt="college 1 seal">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                      <div class="slide-info row">
                        <p class="slide-year col-lg-3">• Dates</p>
                        <div  class="col-lg-9 slide-details">
                          <p>degree</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slide-blurb">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis, nibh vestibulum fringilla mattis, nulla neque dignissim diam, quis maximus diam nunc at eros.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="slide-box">
                  <h3 class="slide-title">college 2</h3>
                    <img class="college2-seal" src="public/images/college2-seal.png" alt="college 2 seal">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                      <div class="slide-info row">
                        <p class="slide-year col-lg-3">• dates</p>
                        <div class="col-lg-9 slide-details">
                          <p>degree</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slide-blurb">
                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis, nibh vestibulum fringilla mattis, nulla neque dignissim diam, quis maximus diam nunc at eros.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="slide-box">
                  <h3 class="slide-title">college 3</h3>
                    <img class="college3-seal" src="public/images/college3-seal.jpg" alt="college3 seal">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                      <div class="slide-info row">
                        <p class="slide-year col-lg-3">• dates</p>
                        <div class="slide-details col-lg-9">
                          <p>degree</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slide-blurb">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis, nibh vestibulum fringilla mattis, nulla neque dignissim diam, quis maximus diam nunc at eros.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="slide-box">
                  <h3 class="slide-title">college 4</h3>
                    <img class="slide-seal college4-logo" src="public/images/college4-seal.png" alt="college 4 logo">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                      <div class="slide-info row">
                        <p class="slide-year col-lg-3">• dates</p>
                        <div class="slide-details col-lg-9">
                          <p>degree</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slide-blurb">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis, nibh vestibulum fringilla mattis, nulla neque dignissim diam, quis maximus diam nunc at eros.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 </body>
</html>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm attempting to change the background by using CSS classes with the background-image property.

CSS

```
.bg-img0 {
  background-image:url("college1.png");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
  z-index: -1;
}
.bg-img1 {
  background-image:url("college2.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
}
.bg-img2 {
  background-image:url("college3.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
}
.bg-img3 {
  background-image:url("college4.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
}

.college1-seal {
  max-height: 12em;
  max-width: 12em;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  }
.college2-seal {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 12em;
  max-width: 12em;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
}
.college3-seal {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 12em;
  max-width: 12em;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
}
.college4-logo {
  max-height: 12em;
  max-width: 12em;
  float: left;
}
 .carousel-inner {
  padding: 1.5em 10.65em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  background-filter:blur(50px);
}
.slide-box {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.25em;
  box-shadow: 0 .5em .333em rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 2em;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slide-title {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 0 .75em;
}
.slide-text {
  margin: 1.5em 0 0 12em;
  padding: 0 0 0 2em;
  height: 12em;
}
.slide-details {
  text-align: left;
}

.slide-info {
  padding: 0 0 1em;
}
```

I've tried a number of different methods.
This makes the most sense but Javascript won't recognize the the picNum variable outside the function.

Jquery/Javascript

```
var picNum = 0;

$(".carousel-control-next").click(function() {
  $("#ed-body").removeClass("bg-img" + picNum);
  var picNum = picNum + 1;
  $("#ed-body").addClass("bg-img" + picNum);
});
```

I've put the variable inside the function and that is the closest I've gotten to this working but the picNum resets to 0 each click so it only goes to the second picture.

```
$(".carousel-control-next").click(function() {
  var picNum = 0;
  $("#ed-body").removeClass("bg-img" + picNum);
  var picNum = picNum + 1;
  $("#ed-body").addClass("bg-img" + picNum);
});
```

Comment: You are declaring the `picName` variable twice: `var picNum = picNum + 1;`. Please remove `var` keyword when you are incrementing the value

Answer (score 3):

I made you a code for a click event for two buttons - `.carousel-control-next` and `.carousel-control-prev`.

The error was in this line:

```
var picNum = picNum + 1;
```

You need it like this:

```
picNum++;
```

I also added an if condition for you, which assigns 0 if the number of the `.bg-img` class is greater than the declared one:

```
if (picNum > count_slide) {
  picNum = 0;
}
```

```js
var picNum = 0;
var count_slide = $('#carouselExampleFade .carousel-item').length - 1;

$(".carousel-control-next").click(function() {
  $("#ed-body").removeClass("bg-img" + picNum);
    picNum++;
    if (picNum > count_slide) {
      picNum = 0;
    }
  $("#ed-body").addClass("bg-img" + picNum);
});

$(".carousel-control-prev").click(function() {
  $("#ed-body").removeClass("bg-img" + picNum);
    picNum--;
    if (picNum < 0) {
      picNum = count_slide;
    }
  $("#ed-body").addClass("bg-img" + picNum);
});
```

```css
.bg-img0 {
  background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/07/03/20/17/abstract-2468874__340.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
  z-index: -1;
}
.bg-img1 {
  background-image:url("https://img5.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/nbig/f/96/blue-luxury-background-sparkle-fon-sinii-blestki.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
}
.bg-img2 {
  background-image:url("https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/red-blue-smoke-on-background_36326-1255.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
}
.bg-img3 {
  background-image:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/15/04/02/water-1330252__340.jpg");
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
}

.college1-seal {
  max-height: 12em;
  max-width: 12em;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  }
.college2-seal {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 12em;
  max-width: 12em;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
}
.college3-seal {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 12em;
  max-width: 12em;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
}
.college4-logo {
  max-height: 12em;
  max-width: 12em;
  float: left;
}
 .carousel-inner {
  padding: 1.5em 10.65em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  background-filter:blur(50px);
}
.slide-box {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.25em;
  box-shadow: 0 .5em .333em rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 2em;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slide-title {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 0 0 .75em;
}
.slide-text {
  margin: 1.5em 0 0 12em;
  padding: 0 0 0 2em;
  height: 12em;
}
.slide-details {
  text-align: left;
}

.slide-info {
  padding: 0 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My name</title>


    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/styles.css">

    <!--- Font Awesome ------->


    <!-- bootstrap script -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body id="ed-body" class="bg-img0">
    <section id="education">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="ed-carousel">
          <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-interval="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="slide-box">
                  <h3 class="slide-title">college 1</h3>
                    <img class="college4-seal" src="public/images/college1-seal.png" alt="college 1 seal">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                      <div class="slide-info row">
                        <p class="slide-year col-lg-3">• Dates</p>
                        <div  class="col-lg-9 slide-details">
                          <p>degree</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slide-blurb">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis, nibh vestibulum fringilla mattis, nulla neque dignissim diam, quis maximus diam nunc at eros.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="slide-box">
                  <h3 class="slide-title">college 2</h3>
                    <img class="college2-seal" src="public/images/college2-seal.png" alt="college 2 seal">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                      <div class="slide-info row">
                        <p class="slide-year col-lg-3">• dates</p>
                        <div class="col-lg-9 slide-details">
                          <p>degree</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slide-blurb">
                        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis, nibh vestibulum fringilla mattis, nulla neque dignissim diam, quis maximus diam nunc at eros.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="slide-box">
                  <h3 class="slide-title">college 3</h3>
                    <img class="college3-seal" src="public/images/college3-seal.jpg" alt="college3 seal">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                      <div class="slide-info row">
                        <p class="slide-year col-lg-3">• dates</p>
                        <div class="slide-details col-lg-9">
                          <p>degree</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slide-blurb">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis, nibh vestibulum fringilla mattis, nulla neque dignissim diam, quis maximus diam nunc at eros.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="slide-box">
                  <h3 class="slide-title">college 4</h3>
                    <img class="slide-seal college4-logo" src="public/images/college4-seal.png" alt="college 4 logo">
                    <div class="slide-text">
                      <div class="slide-info row">
                        <p class="slide-year col-lg-3">• dates</p>
                        <div class="slide-details col-lg-9">
                          <p>degree</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slide-blurb">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec convallis, nibh vestibulum fringilla mattis, nulla neque dignissim diam, quis maximus diam nunc at eros.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


    <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using `$('#carouselExampleFade .carousel-item').length` as a limit (instead of hard-coded `3`) would be better in case author needs more or less items.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you! More correct would be like this - `$ ('# carouselExampleFade .carousel-item').length - 1`. And I fixed it.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I don't  have enough rep to upvote this but it did exactly what I was trying to do. I'm new to the industry and this community has been wildly helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: Hello. No problem :) You can just select my answer as solved by checking the box to the left of my answer. I was glad to help.